# Help with calculus 1 derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm taking calculus. There is a particular problem I have no idea how to solve. There are two questions that use the following table.

x $\,$ $\,$0 1 2

f(x) 1 2 1

f’(x) 2 1 3

g(x) 2 1 1

g’(x) 1 3 1

h(x) 3 2 4

h’(x) 2 1 2

Find (f · g)'(1) (This is a multiplication symbol and not a composition symbol.)

Find $(\frac{f}{g}$)'(2)

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

So the question is asking you what the derivative of the the function $r(x) = f(x) *g(x)$ is at $x =1$ and the derivative of $s(x) = f(x)/g(x)$ at $x = 2$. The theorems you will need are the product rule (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) and the quotient rule (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule).

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** Using the following rules:

$$(f(x)g(x))'=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x).$$

And

$$(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})'=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}.$$

May it helps!